# How to copy animation data without affecting the position

Tags: animation

I want to copy the animation data of each of my letters, without affecting the position.
I'm linking the letter e to the letter T, its animating perfectly but it's snapping to the position where the T is, and I want the letter e to be next to the T.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, I need the e letter to fly in like the T letter, which spins around 360 and also affects the scale., so how can I do this easily without having manually to do it for each letter?

Comment: i would work with empties or animation nodes or geometry nodes, tbh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one solution is to create an empty and give that empty just the scale and rotation animation.

Then click on your object (letter) and link the animation data to that empty.

example:

[image]

here the empty cube has rotation + scale animation.
Then i linked the cubes to the empties animation.

blend file:

[image]

Comment: Here's my Blender file, I've missed something... As you can see the Empty cube is animating, I have linked each letters origin to its centre, but its doing the same thing, the letters are collapsing all in the centre of the world.

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=o9Jx5Pxx" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/o9Jx5Pxx/)

Comment: https://ibb.co/3TrCYc9

Comment: first delete your location animation of your empty, as i wrote, this will be linked to. So if you link your objects to an empty WITH location animation, it will be copied to. here your empty animation data: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kcg4W.png

Comment: second: apply scale + rotation  of your letters

Comment: third: make sure your objects origin points are all in the middle of the letters so that it looks good when it rotates

Comment: fourth: select your letters, shift select your empty -> ctrl -l -> link animation data.

Comment: another hint: you should start your animation of your empty with scale = 1, else the animation will "jump" -> result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH671.gif